# Pass arguments to a function called within a switch in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

When running my PowerShell script I want to call a function depending on the first argument which is passed along. For this I use a switch.

```
function veeamScript([string]$command) {
    switch($command)
    {
        install
        {
            install #calls a function which doesn't need arguments
        }
        create
        {
            create($name, $server, $username, $password)
        }
        Default
        {
            echo "The help text"
        }
    }
}

scriptName($command)
```

If I call the script like this

```
scriptName.ps1 create myname myserver theusername thepassword
```

It should calls this function

```
function create($name, $server, $username, $password) {
    $check=checkIfInstalled # This calls another function which works and is either true or false

    if ($check -eq $true)
    {
        echo "Name: $name"
        echo "Server: $server"
        echo "Username: $username"
        echo "Password: $password"
        ...
    } else
    {
        echo "ERROR ..."
    }
}
```

However the echoes are all "empty" (e.g. after the *Name:* ).

It looks like the arguments aren't being passed through the switch, much less to the function. I added an echo within the switch before the function is being called and the echo is also empty.

```
create
        {
            echo "$name" # Also tried it without the double quotation marks, didn't work
            create($name, $server, $username, $password)
        }
```

Does anyone know how I can call my script, let the switch decide which function is called (depending on the first argument) and pass on the rest of the arguments?

Comment: The proper way to call a function is to use space as the delimiter between the function and its parametesr. This allows the items to be parsed properly --> `create $name $server $username $password`. You will need your function defined in the code before the function call happens. With that said, since `VeeamScript` only has one parameter, only `create` will be bound in your script call because of the unquoted spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `$args` automatic variable and the `@` splat operator:

```
# scriptName.ps1

# split arguments into first,rest
$command,$actualArguments = $args

# check that command name is valid
if($command -in 'create','install')
{
  # user provided a valid command name, let's execute it with the remaining args
  & $command @actualArguments
}
else
{
  # throw an error or show usage text
  "Usage: ..."
}
```

Now it will work with both named and positional parameter arguments, and you don't even need a `switch` :-)

For more information about splatting, see the [`about_Splatting` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting)